# Using an expression lambda on a generic method on a generic collection

Tags: c#, generics, mvvm, lambda

I am trying to understand the below use of a lambda expression.  This code is taken from Josh Smith's excellent MVVM demo code (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090055).

A method is called as follows:

```
AllCustomersViewModel workspace =
                this.Workspaces.FirstOrDefault(vm => vm is AllCustomersViewModel)
                as AllCustomersViewModel;
```

As used here, `FirstOrDefault` has the following definition, as identified by Visual Studio 2010:

```
public static TSource FirstOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate);
```

It is not clear to me

1. How does `vm` get its type?  It is not defined elsewhere in the object instance.
2. How does `FirstOrDefault(vm => vm is AllCustomersViewModel)` satisfy the `source` parameter requirement of `FirstOrDefault`?  Is this somehow being implied?

I have been trying to use these resources to parse this out:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `vm` gets its type because `Workspaces` is a collection that contains a specific type.  `vm` is automatically inferred to be that type.
2. The `source` parameter of `FirstOrDefault` is `Workspaces.`  It's an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) on `IEnumerable<T>`, so the instance you call it on takes the place of the first parameter.  That's what the `this` in the method signature means.

Comment: Thank you .. you hit all of the gaps in my understanding precisely!

Comment: Is there a name for the mechanism that infers vm's type from Workspaces?  I realize that this behavior must be something given by the C# spec, but does it have a name?  Thanks again.

Comment: @Bill: It's just type inference, as applied to generic methods.

Comment: The technical name for that feature is indeed just "type inference." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference

Comment: @Jon:  Yes, now I see it.  TSource is given by the type of the members of the generic collection (Workspaces) on which the generic method (FirstOrDefault) is called.

Answer (score 2):

Others have answered the question itself. Just as an aside though, this code would be clearer as:

```
AllCustomersViewModel workspace = this.Workspaces.OfType<AllCustomersViewModel>()
                                                 .FirstOrDefault();
```

Why bother creating your own operator when LINQ already includes one? ([OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx))

Answer (score 1):

The `<TSource, bool>` predicate has the first parameter inferred as mentioned above, the second parameter (the boolean) is then supplying by the lambda expression `vm => vm is AllCustomersViewModel`

The meaning is give me the first (or the default value if none exists) Workspace where the item is an instance of AllCustomersViewModel.